# reduce array of dictionaries

Tags: python, reduce

I have an array of dictionaries that I want to reduce

```
foo = [{'value': 45}, {'value': 2}, {'value': 3}, {'value': 0}]
reduce(lambda x, y: x['value']+y['value'] , foo)
```

gives me the following error

```
TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

what I ended up doing was to first create a simple array using a comprehension.

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [x['value'] for x in foo])
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please post your desired output.

Comment: For some reason when the number of dicts exceeds 2, `reduce()` does not work. I am not sure why yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reduce(function, [a, b, c])` is equivalent to `function(function(a, b), c)`.
The result of `function` must therefore be suitable to act as the first argument of `function`.

To illustrate, this works:

```
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: {'value': x['value']+y['value']} , foo)
{'value': 50}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using `reduce` wrong.

```
from functools import reduce

foo = [{'value': 45}, {'value': 2}, {'value': 3}, {'value': 0}]
reduce(lambda acc, item: acc + item['value'], foo, 0)
```

Once reduces list items against an accumulator, not list items against each other.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to sum the integer values

You could just reduce using a builtin from the operator library:

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import add, itemgetter

reduce(add, map(itemgetter('value'), foo))
```